# Shared printer keeps coming back after removal

Tags: printer, print-server

So to start we have a domain with a single print server. The print server is running Windows 2008 R2. All our workstations (computers used by our end users) are running Windows 7 Professional. In the past printers were deployed with FOG which is also our network imaging system. The printers are first added to our print server and are set to be shared. FOG would then be able to add these shared printers to workstations.

Just recently I noticed that one printer seemed to be added to nearly every workstation including workstations it should not be on. Let's call this printer printer#1. Every time printer#1 was removed from a workstation it would instantly come back after a reboot or just logging off and logging back on. I tried nearly everything. I removed the printer driver from print management on the workstation as well but it would come back along with printer#1. Printer#1 would not come back though if I disconnected the workstation from our network after removing it. Once it was plugged back in it would came back.

Thankfully for us we had plans to remove this printer from our network for good. We also at this point decided to change our deployment of printers by using group policy to add and remove printers to workstations. FOG had all of the print management it was doing removed. So no printers are being added or removed by it anymore. After removing the printer from the print server it wouldn't come back after being removed. At this point I made a few group policies to push out a few other printers. Those work just fine.

Now another printer (one that was added before using group policy) is doing the exact same thing. This printer has never been touched in any of my group policies. All problems and symptoms are the same as printer#1. I did as much research as I could online and found if a workstation has network discovery turned off after removing the printer it will not come back. That sadly can't be the solution for us. I also have tried removing the printer from our print server. When it is removed, it will not come back on workstations. However, once I add the printer back on the print server it does come back on workstations.

I've read suggestions online that a previous group policy could be adding them. That is not the case for us. We never added or removed printers in the past and this printer has not been in any of our new policies. This also occurred with printer#1 before we used group policies for printers. Both of these printers has never added itself to all our computers. It seems to just come back on those in which had the printer added at some point. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Walls of text hurt the soul... [paragraphs please](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/paragraphs/)!

Comment: Please use some newlines and paragraphs. I'm not even going to try to read that.

Comment: I just broke it down into paragraphs. Sorry.